# Durandal computed prototype methods

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

Is it possible to define a computed property on my view model prototype? As far as I can tell, there is no way to access a proper `this` value at the time of declaration.

I can put it inside the constructor, but then it'll be redefined for each instance as you know. So in the end this is just a question of performance.

My AMD module for my view model:

```
function viewModel(){
    // this.someComputed works
}

viewModel.prototype.someComputed = ko.pureComputed(function(){

}/*, no context yet..? */);

viewModel.prototype.activate = function(){
    // 'this' is an instance of the view model (I presume)
    // should I attach it here?
};

return viewModel;
```

Comment: Thid doesn't really have any thing to do with Durandal per se, does it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wanted to mention it since I'm able to use Durandal's `activate` method which exposes the function instance through `this`. As a side question which I think you know the answer to: even if I declare a function inside the constructor, doesn't modern browsers add it to the prototype anyway?

Comment: No, they don't (and can't). But what they *do* do is reuse the same underlying function code across multiple function objects. So really, it's just the cost of the computed itself and an object (the function object the code gets attached to). It's not too bad, objects are fairly cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a computed property on my view model prototype? As far as I can tell, there is no way to access a proper `this` value at the time of declaration.

Correct. So the answer is no, you can't use computeds on prototype methods.